# JOIN when one table has no rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.date_registered, p.time_created 
    FROM users u JOIN 
        prospect_notes p 
        ON u.id=p.subject_id  
    WHERE u.allocated_instructors = 668
    AND p.time_created = (SELECT MAX(p2.time_created) FROM prospect_notes p2 WHERE p2.subject_id = p.subject_id)
    ORDER BY p.time_created;
```

My problem is that when there are no rows in the `prospect_notes` table which match the following:

`AND p.time_created = (SELECT MAX(p2.time_created) FROM prospect_notes p2 WHERE p2.subject_id = p.subject_id)`

I get no result.

Instead, I want all the rows in the `users` table to return (presumably `p.time_created` would be NULL in such cases).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to be careful because of the `JOIN` clause.  Presumably, if there are no matches for the correlated subquery, there are no matches in the `JOIN` either.

So, use `LEFT JOIN` and move the logic to the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.date_registered, p.time_created 
FROM users u LEFT JOIN 
     prospect_notes p 
     ON u.id = p.subject_id LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT p2.subject_id, MAX(p2.time_created) as max_time_created
      FROM prospect_notes p2
      GROUP BY p2.subject_id
     ) p2
     ON p2.subject_id = p.subject_id AND p2.time_created = p.time_created
WHERE u.allocated_instructors = 668 
ORDER BY p.time_created;
```

That said, if you only want `time_created` from `prospect_notes`, then use a simpler query:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.date_registered, MAX(p.time_created)
FROM users u LEFT JOIN 
     prospect_notes p 
     ON u.id = p.subject_id 
WHERE u.allocated_instructors = 668 
GROUP BY u.id  -- okay, assuming id is unique or a primary key
ORDER BY MAX(p.time_created);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `LEFT JOIN` this clause permit you to have `NULL` values in the right table.

Try :

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.date_registered, p.time_created 
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN prospect_notes p 
    ON u.id=p.subject_id  
WHERE u.allocated_instructors = 668
AND p.time_created = (SELECT MAX(p2.time_created) FROM prospect_notes p2 WHERE p2.subject_id = p.subject_id)
ORDER BY p.time_created;
```